# Having more than one multiple field to post into "post_content"

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, variables, post

I'm trying to make a form application with multiple fields to write info in.

Heres the code im working on right now.

```
$type = trim($_POST['Type']);
$new_post = array(
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_content' => $_POST['description'],
    'post_parent' => 65,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'topic'
);
$topic_meta = array(
    'forum_id'  => $new_post['post_parent']
);
$topic_id = bbp_insert_topic($new_post, $topic_meta);
wp_redirect(get_permalink($topic_id));
exit;
```

I have more fields which are documented by the name `customfieldone` and `customfieldtwo` which I would like to add to the topic it creates from the form.

With that code above it only posts the text which is in `description` into the topic.